# Type is not assignable to type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint Type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Hi I'm trying to implement active routine & repository logic with typescript. But having some problems dealing with generic types.

I have an abstract `BaseModel` which has create method that returns itself and subtype of itself. To do so I said it will return `BaseModel`. In repository which has a generic type extends from `BaseModel`, I wrapped my model methods and used generic type as returned value. But when I do that it gives me below error.

`'BaseModel' is not assignable to type 'T'.   'BaseModel' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'BaseModel'.`

When I googled it, found some answers like it may happen when re-assigning the generic or dublicating in nested structures. But neither I'm assigning something nor define same generic over and over

Why I'm getting this type error and how do I solve it ?

Here is some part of code.

BaseModel.ts

```
export abstract class BaseModel {
  protected constructor(private attributes: any[] = []) {
  }

  create(attributes: any[] = null): BaseModel {
    return this;
  }
  // ...
}
```

BaseRepository.ts

```
export class Repository<T extends BaseModel> {
  constructor(private model: T) {
  }

  create(attributes: any[]): T {
    return this.model.create(attributes);
  }
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `create` of `BaseModel` returns `BaseModel` which is not assignable to derived type (subtype). It should return `this`:

```
create(attributes: any[] = null): this { ...
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAQwEYGcZQQY3pgNglFOAIQOAFkIATYXOAbwFgAoOOMKCGYbYKuTBAB2aKAFds0ABQcAlgDcE3RDHSykY7igBciIQE8A2gF04AXjgmAlAxZsAvizsCowJcClK1GrboQGTOAAfOCExXDoLMIirXRgAC1kiJlY2OFcYMSghOASkgG5nR1SAehK4ADoqlmKWUEhYAXxCOAAlYEgUWRhofQAeABU4UG4hKiJSFApqWgA%20W1TBEXQJHqgZKAV3OABbGdxdAZsUhydF13dPVU2fYB09I2NYuCGTtIysnLyUCr2aXAqmAu3Cu3k0dyshVSxTYZUq1WY9iAA)

More on polymorphic this types [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#polymorphic-this-types).

Comment: well that make sense