# using a generic within a function type

Tags: typescript

I have two functions (one for web and one for native) that I'd like to share the same type. The issue is I can't seem to figure out how to get this to work. Here is the function with inline types:

```
export const useRoute = <RouteName extends AllRoutes>(
  routeRequest: string,
) => {

  const route = <do work here>

  return {
    routeName: route.name as RouteName,
    params: route.params as RouteParams<RouteName>,
  }
}
```

What I would like is to have something like:

```
export type UseRouteFunctionType<
  RouteName extends AllRoutesType
> = (
  routeRequest: string,
) => {
  routeName: RouteName
  params: RouteParams<RouteName>
}
```

the thing is I can't seem to figure out how to apply the above to a function in such a way that the generics work correctly.

Comment: You need to move the Generic parameters after the `=`

Comment: @EliasSchablowski thanks, but now in use I get something like `Type '"Home"' is not assignable to type 'RouteName'.
              '"Home"' is assignable to the constraint of type 'RouteName', but 'RouteName' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint ...`

Comment: This is related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63260198/type-is-not-assignable-to-type-t-but-t-could-be-instantiated-with-a-differe, basically AllRoutesType => Home, so Home !=> AllRoutesType, this usually comes up when you use unions, though this is a semi-"catch all" error of this type

Comment: You can obtain the precise type of your function and export it via `typeof`. `export type UseRouteFunctionType = typeof useRoute;`. Less is more.